# EXCEL VBA: How to copy information from one worksheet to another, merging/updating duplicate rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, one that is my master copy(MC), and one I am trying to extract data from (EXTRACT). My MC already has some information on it, and will, as I intend to extract data from an updated version of EXTRACT each day. I think I know how to just copy info over, but I want it to check between the two, compare each row to all other rows in the other workbook, if there are exact copies, ignore them, and if there are almost exact, with a difference on a date, then update the date in MC. Then all new rows, I just want to be copied over in the next available rows. I don't know if that all makes sense, so if you have questions, feel free to ask and I will do my best to explain. I am relatively new at VBA, so I don't really know where to start for this. If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated. And if you can help, if you could include pseudocode in it so I can understand how it works, that would be great!

Here's what I have so far. I did some work over the weekend, but not sure for some parts of it, such as sometimes there will be two rows that I am pulling from with the same information, but a different date, and how to, after the first instance is changed, not change the second instance, with the original data, or add a new row. As you can see, I am trying to store the cell location in an array and check against that, but I don't know if that is how it should be done or not. I don't know if that is clear or not, but you might be able to understand with the pictures, which I will add below. Not all of the information shown is 100% accurate since some of it is not mine to share, so I edited some of the data to not be seen:

```
Public Sub Checker()
    
    Dim iloop As Integer                'Created variable iloop as an integer
    Dim iloop2 As Integer               'Created variable iloop2 as an integer
    Dim lines As Integer                'Created variable lines as an integer
    Dim wb As Workbook                  'Creates variable wb - Source, or Book1
    Dim MC As Workbook                  'Creates variable MC - Master Copy
    Dim celltxt As String               'Creates string variable
    Dim celltx As String                'Creates string variable
    Dim copied(1 To 1) As Range         'Creates an array with range type variables

    Set lines = 1
    Set MC = Workbooks("Master Final SOs Testing")      'Sets the MC cariable to Master Final SOs Testing
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1 (3)")     'Sets the wb variable to Book1 (3)
    Set iloop = 2                       'Var for Book1
    Set iloop2 = 2                      'Var for MC
    'if we get workbook instance then
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then           'If wb actually has something, then...
        While wb.Cells(iloop, 2) <> ""                                  'As long as (iloop, 2) in Book is not empty, then
            While MC.Cells(iloop2, 2) <> ""                             'As long as (iloop2, 2) in MC is not empty, then
                If wb.Cells(iloop, 2) <> MC.Cells(iloop2, 2) Then       'If the SOs do not match then
                    iloop2 = iloop2 + 1                                 'Add to iloop2 in MC to move to next row
                Else
                    If MC.Cells(iloop2, 2) <> copied() Then
                        wb.Activate                                         'Else, activate the Scheduled Ship date cell, select it, copy it, then paste it in the right cell in MC
                        wb.Cells(iloop, 4).Select
                        wb.Cells(iloop, 4).Copy
                        MC.Cells(iloop2, 4).PasteSpecial
                        wb.Cells(iloop, 1).Select                          'Selects the first header
                        celltxt = wb.Selection.Text                        'sets the variable to equal the selected cell text
                        MC.Cells(iloop2, 1).Select                         'Selects the first header
                        celltx = MC.Selection.Text                         'sets the variable to equal the selected cell text
                        copied(lines) = MC.Cells(iloop2, 2)                'Adds the current cell range that was just copied to the array in the newest open slot
                        lines = lines + 1                                  'Adds 1 to lines for next time a range needs to be added to the array
                        ReDim Preserve copied(1 To UBound(copied) + 1) As Range     'Adds a new slot to the array while keeping/preserving the data already in it
                        
                        If wb.InStr(1, celltxt, "Y") > 0 And MC.InStr(1, celltx, "R") > 0 Then          'If the line is Y Packaged, and it was in the rack, change it to be in the basket
                            MC.Cells(1, iloop2).Value = B
                        End If
                    End If
                    iloop2 = iloop2 + 1
                End If
            Wend
            iloop = iloop + 1                                           'Add 1 to iloop to move to next SO in Book
            iloop2 = 2                                                  'Reset iloop2 to 2 to restart the process
        Wend
    End If


End Sub
```

[Book3 (1) picture, what I am pulling from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzimp.png)
[MC picture, what I am adding to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyb3C.png)

Comment: Since you *"know how to just copy info over"*, why don't you put it into code so we can see from it what these worksheets and workbooks are called, how many rows and columns they have, etc. Then describe in detail what defines a duplicate and what a different row. Also, add some screenshots of the worksheets and some sample data.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I just added the updated code. I worked on it a little over the weekend, so I was able to make some headway, but I also updated some new problems I realized I need to figure out. And I added a screenshot of both worksheets